# $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\log(x_n)}{n}$ if , $x_n = 2x_{n−1} + 1$ if $n$ is odd, $3x_{n−1} + 2$ if $n$ is even.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Define a sequence $(x_n)_n$ by $x_0 = 1$, $x_n = 2x_{n−1} + 1$ if $n$ is odd, $3x_{n−1} + 2$ if $n$ is even.
Then

(a) $\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\log(x_n)}{n}$ does not exist.

(b)  $\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\log(x_n)}{n} = \dfrac{\log6}{2}$

(c) $\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\log(x_n)}{n} =\log5$

(d) $\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\log(x_n)}{n} =\dfrac{5}{2}$ .

Well,  I checked the first few terms and the sequence keeps on increasing, I guess the limit doesn't exist. What should I look for, $(x_n)$ or $\dfrac{\log(x_n)}{n}$? I looked at $(x_{2n})$and $(x_{2n-1})$,and their limits is $-1$ and this doesn't give me anything. Please don't give me direct answers, give me hints or intuition.

Comment: Did you check $x_n$ or $\log(x_n)/n$? The latter sequence is bounded, but doesn't necessarily have a limit. Here's a big hint: suppose that the $+1$ and $+2$ terms in the definition weren't there. Could you see how to write $\log(x_n)/n$ in explicit form? From there it's just a matter of showing that those small additions don't affect things asymptotically.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thank you I got it

Comment: @lucas in general, I would avoid posting multiple-choice questions on this site, as these have the connotation of homework/exam questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x_{n+2}\begin{cases}3x_{n+1} + 2=3(2x_n+1)+2=6x_n+5&n\text{ is odd}\\ 2x_{n+1}+1=2(3x_n+2) +1=6x_n+5&n\text{ is even}\end{cases}=6x_n+5$

So $x_1= 1$.  $x_3 = 6*1+5; x_5 = 6(6*1+5)+5 = 6^2 + 6*5 + 5; x_7=6^3+ 6^2*5 + 6*5 + 5$.

So by induction  $x_{2n-1}= 6^{n-1} + 6^{n-2}*5 + 6^{n-3} + ..... + 6*5 + 5=$

$6^{n-1} + 5(6^{n-2} + ...... + 1)=$

$6^{n-1} + 5\frac {6^{n-1} -1}{6-1} = $

$6^{n-1} + 6^{n-1}-1=2*6^{n-1}-1$.

(Example:  $x_5=x_{2*3 -1} = 2*6^2 -1 =71$ and, indeed, $x_1 = 1; $x_2=3; x_3=11;x_4= 2*11+1=23; x_5 = 3*23+2 = 71$.)

Likewise $x_2 = 3;x_4 = 6*3 + 5$ and $x_6= 6^2*3 +  6*5 + 5$ and $x_{2n} = 6^{n-1}*3 + 5(6^{n-2}+... + 1)=$

$6^{n-1}*3 + 5\frac{6^{n-1}-1}{6-1}= 6^{n-1}*4 - 1$.

(so for example $x_6=x_{2*3} = 6^2*4-1 = 143$ and $x_5=71$ so $x_6=2*71 + 1 = 143$)

And that's pretty much it:

So $\lim_{2n\to \infty} \frac {\log x_{2n}}{2n} = \lim_{2n\to \infty}\frac {\log (4*6^{n-1} -1)}{2n}=$

$\lim_{2n\to \infty}\frac {\log 4*6^{n-1} }{2n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {(n-1)\log 6 + \log 4}{2n}=$

$\lim_{2n\to \infty}\frac {n-1}{2n}\log 6 = \frac {\log 6}2$.

so $\lim_{n\to \infty; n\text{ even}}\frac {\log x_n}n = \frac {\log 6}2$.

ANd $\lim_{2n-1\to \infty} \frac {\log x_{2n-1}}{2n-1} = \lim_{2n-1\to \infty}\frac {\log (6^{n-1} -1)}{2n-1}=$

$\lim_{2n-1\to \infty}\frac {\log 6^{n-1} }{2n-1}=\lim_{2n-1\to \infty}\frac {(n-1)\log 6 }{2n+1}=$

$\lim_{2n-1\to \infty}\frac {n-1}{2n-1}\log 6 = \frac {\log 6}2$.

So $\lim_{n\to \infty; n\text{ odd}}\frac {\log x_n}n = \frac {\log 6}2$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** show that $x_{n+2}=6x_n+5$. Deduce formulas for $(x_{2n})$ and $(x_{2n+1})$.

Answer (score 0):

We simplify the series, and only look at even $n$. we get the recursion $$x_{2n}=2x_{2n-1}+1=6x_{2n-2}+5$$
(we used the definition of the series twice)

from here it is straight forward that $\lim_{n→∞} \dfrac{\log(x_{2n})}{n}=\log6$. and with the uniqueness of the limit, we get the answer.

thus (b) is correct

Comment: The correct answer is (b)

Comment: yup, that was a typo, the methodology I gave here yields (b) as the correct answer

Comment: $\dfrac {\log(x_{2n}) }{n} = \dfrac{\log6+ \log(x_{2n-2} + 5/6)}{n}$ and?

Comment: by recursion $x_{2n + j} = 6(6(6(.........(x_j) + 5)+5)+..... 5) = 6^nx_j + 6^{n-1}*5 + 6^{n-2}*5+....... + 5$ where $x_j = \begin{cases} x_1 = 1\\x_2=3\end{cases}$.... And $\lim \frac{\log[6^nx_j + 6^{n-1}*5 + 6^{n-2}*5+....... + 5]}{2n+j} = ???$

Comment: Note:  $ 6^{n-1}*5 + 6^{n-2}*5+....... + 5$ is not significant compared to $6^nx_j$ for large $n$.  And $\frac {\log x_{2n+j}}{2n+j}\approx \frac {\log (6^nx_j)}{2n+j}=??????$.